# Sharepoint Replicator activity doesn't stop

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a problem with a replicator activity in a workflow. 
I have set InitialChildData to a list Approvers.
This list is well initialized during my event Replicator Initialized.

When i'm in debug mode, and try to look at the workflow, i see that it get out of the Replicator activity once all approvers approved the item. The tricky part is that it gets in the Replicator activity again just after leaving it, creating a new task assigned to the first approver of my list.

Do you have any idea where it can come from ?

Thanks a lot for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question resolved, 
My workflow was starting when an item was updated. So i put an event receiver on the workflow, and looked at his status to check if the task was finished or not